# How to override Robolectric application?

Tags: java, android, junit, robolectric

I've inherited legacy Android project and started to add Robolectric 3 and JUnit 4 test cases. Sadly currently the main Application class can't be initialized because of spaghetti code and frameworks that don't work in Robolectric. I'd like to replace my application class for the tests. But Robolectric crashes before I can even update the `RuntimeEnviroment.application` variable.
Is there a way to disable manifest application creation in Robolectric?

Here's what I've been trying to do:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = Config.NONE)
public class TestClass {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RuntimeEnvironment.application = new Application();
    }

    @Test
    public void testFunc() {
        // some testing goes here
    }
}
```

But it fails due to Parse framework:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.robolectric.util.SimpleFuture.run(SimpleFuture.java:61)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAsyncTask$2.run(ShadowAsyncTask.java:96)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:230)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:85)
    at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.post(Scheduler.java:72)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAsyncTask.execute(ShadowAsyncTask.java:93)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java)
    at com.facebook.internal.Utility.loadAppSettingsAsync(Utility.java:771)
    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:167)
    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:146)
    at com.parse.FacebookController$FacebookSdkDelegateImpl.initialize(FacebookController.java:187)
    at com.parse.FacebookController.initialize(FacebookController.java:70)
    at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:108)
    at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(ParseFacebookUtils.java:92)
    at MyApplication.initParse(StrongliftsApplication.java:174)
    at MyApplication.onCreate(StrongliftsApplication.java:112)
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:140)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:433)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:240)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So it happens that Robolectric developers forsaw this situation and `@Config` directive allows application override. Also manifest override didn't help me at all so it could be removed.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, application = MyTestApplication.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void testFunc() {
        // some testing goes here
    }
}
```

Since our application uses singleton pattern I had to also init singleton instance. I ignore all other initalization on purpouse since it was mostly initting frameworks. Here's what my MyTestApplication looks like:

```
public class MyTestApplication extends MyApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MyApplication.instance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the MyTestApplication class too ? atleast a basic version of your MyTestApplication.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler solution.

Just put a class `Test<YouApplicationName>` in test sources and **Robolectric will pick up it.

So if your application name is `org.my.package.SuperApplication` then create class `TestSuperapplication` in folder `test\java\org\my\package\` and you don't need to provide anything in the `@Config` section.

Comment: Nice to know, didn't find it in the documentation, thanks! Although I prefer to explictly state my mock application, that way the next developer will know what's happening. Also this allows different applications clases for different tests.

Comment: Sure. It is your code. I don't think you ever will use second application